# Selection in the Controller is not matching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this error when I am trying to remove the item from the Cart table.

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Panier/RemoveFromCart/1.   This URL seems to be fine with me.  It should branch to the PanierController at RemoveCart.   I don't understand why it is not branching.
Thanks

Index.cshtml

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }

 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
         $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
             // Get the id from the link
             var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
             if (recordToDelete != '') {
                 // Perform the ajax post
                 $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", {"id": recordToDelete },
                     function (data) {
                    // Successful requests get here
                    // Update the page elements
                    if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                        $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    } else {
                        $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                    }
                    $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                    $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                });
            }
        });
    });
 </script>

 <h3>
     <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
 </p>
 <div id="update-message">
 </div>
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th>
             Produit
         </th>
         <th>
             Prix (unitaire)
         </th>
         <th>
             Quantite
         </th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>
     @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
     {
         <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description,"Details", "Store", new { id = 
                    item.ProduitId }, null)
             </td>
             <td>
                 @item.Produit.Prix
             </td>
             <td id="item-count-@item.ProduitId">
                 @item.Quantite
             </td>
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink("Enlever du panier", "RemoveFromCart", "Panier", new { id =
                       item.ProduitId }, null)
             </td>
         </tr>
     }
     <tr>
         <td>
             Total
         </td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td id="cart-total">
              @Model.CartTotal
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

PanierController.cs

```
 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Controllers
 {
     public class PanierController : Controller
     {

         Tp1WebStoreDBEntities dbProduit = new Tp1WebStoreDBEntities();   

         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
         {
             // Remove the item from the cart
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

             // Get the name of the product to display confirmation
             string produitDescription = dbProduit.Paniers
                 .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.Description;

             // Remove from cart
             int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

             // Display the confirmation message
             var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
             {
                 Message = Server.HtmlEncode(produitDescription) +
                     " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                 CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                 CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                 ItemCount = itemCount,
                 DeleteId = id
             };

             return View("Details");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `RemoveFromCart` controller action is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute meaning that it is **ONLY** accessible by POST verbs. But in your view you seem to have generated some action link to it:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Enlever du panier", 
    "RemoveFromCart", 
    "Panier", 
    new { id = item.ProduitId }, 
    null
)
```

But as you are well aware, an `Html.ActionLink` translates into an `<a>` tag in your markup which obviously is sending a GET request to the server when clicked.

So basically you have 3 possibilities here:

1. Use an `Html.BeginForm` instead of an ActionLink to refer to this action which would allow you to send a POST request
2. Get rid of the `[HttpPost]` attribute from your `RemoveFromCart` action
3. AJAXify the anchor which would allow you to use a POST request.

Comment: I looked at the MVC Music Store example and I removed the AJAX from it because it was not working.  I should also remove the POST verbs also

Comment: If you removed the AJAX request then this explains why your code isn't working. When you click on the link, the browser is simply redirecting to the `href` that this link is pointing to by sending a GET request. There's no longer any javascript that would prevent this default action. You'd better figure out why your AJAX code isn't working instead of stripping stuff from the demo and then asking why your code isn't working as expected. It's normal that it won't work as expected if you remove parts from it.

Comment: I tried to have the Ajax working but I didn't find any proper solution to fix it.  here is the error from the Ajax Unhandled exception at line 50, column 5 in http://localhost:49259/Panier/AddToCart/1

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: It appears that you forgot to include the `jquery.js` script itself in your page. The `$` function is part of jquery, so you must include the base script **BEFORE** any other script that relies on it.